# 500 error with Debug = False instead of 404

Tags: python, django

In Django 1.7 application:

```
# settings.py

DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1']

# urls.py
#.....
from myapp.views import handler404
handler404 = handler404

#myapp/views.py
def handler404(request):
  return render(request, '404.html')
```

But still it throws 500 error instead of 404. How come? Is there any way to make it generate 404 instead of 500 even of the server when the page is really not found?

UPDATE:

Even with Debug = True it shows the standard Django 404 page.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation (docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/views/)

```
#from myapp.views import handler404
handler404 = 'myapp.views.handler404'
```

Comment: are you trying to guess the answer?

Comment: you need to provide a better explanation to your answer why should they try this?